# Proof: A matrix with $m$ rows and $n$ colums has $nm$ entries.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

How to prove *rigorously* the following statement:

> A matrix (a collection of numbers $a_{ij}:1\leq i \leq m, 1\leq j \leq n)$   with $m$ rows and $n$ colums has $nm$ entries.

By rigorously I mean to prove the statement as a logical consequence of some axioms, proved theorems and definitions.

To me it is obvious that it has $mn$ entries since you only have to multiply the number of rows with the number of colums.

Nevertheless I could not prove this rigorously - i.e as a logical consequence of the definitons and axioms.

Comment: What is your definition of matrix?

Comment: I only know the informal definition of a matrix as a rectangular. array of numbers

Comment: Given the points you're raising (e.g., how do we know that $1$-by-$1$ is $1$, and how do we know that $m+1$-by-$n$ is $n$ more than $m$-by-$n$), I must ask: What is your definition of "rectangular array"?  You say that you could not prove your proposition "as a logical consequence of the definitions and axioms"—what are your definitions and axioms?  Perhaps the problem is that you don't have a clear enough picture of what those are.  I suspect these can't be defined to make this proposition provable but non-trivial; either the definitions won't be sufficient, or they will, but it'll be easy.

Comment: You will have to give some kind of definition. For example, is a matrix a collection of numbers $a_{ij}:1\le i\le m, 1\le j\le n$? Or is it the collection of numbers which encode a linear map between vector spaces $L:V\to W$ relative to defined bases for $V$ and $W$, where $\dim(V)=m$ and $\dim(W)=n$? Or is it something quite different. Note that the vector space definition is more complete because the associative law for functions (linear maps) yields an associative multiplication for matrices, while the array definition leaves this to be motivated and defined.

Comment: I edited the question and gave a definition of matrix. How to prove it with this definition?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Proceed by induction on $m+n$ with $m \ge 1, n \ge 1$. Base case $m+n=2$ then $m = 1 = n$ and the matrix will have $mn=1$ entry as expected.

Now assume inductively this is true for $m+n = N$, and look at some matrix $A$ with $m+n = N+1$. Remove a row from this matrix $A$ and apply the inductive hypothesis. Adding another row should add another $n$ entries.

Can you finish this?

Comment: Yes. I had already thought of induction. Nevertheless I have some questions. How do you know that a matrix with $1$ row and $1$ column has only one entry? How do you know that adding antoher row should add another $n$ entries?

Comment: @user50224 These should be axiomatic

Comment: but they are not part of the ZFC axioms. I didn't know that these were axioms so where can I look up the axioms of matrices?

Comment: @user50224 they are axiomatic definitions of what *matrix* is. See Pedro Tamaroff's question in the top of your queue